# XML File Input Map/Reduce Hadoop Windows Server

Tags: xml, hadoop, mapreduce, windows-server-2008, hadoop-streaming

I am working on Hadoop Platform (by HortonWorks) installed on Windows Server and coding Map/Reduce files in C#.

I have an input folder with 100k xml files. I want to read each xml file and write each tag in one row. Please follow below example.

INPUT:

```
<Person>
    <a>1</a>
    <b>2</b>
    <c>3</c>
</Person>
```

OUTPUT
1,2,3
....
....

Can you please provide me inputs on how I should read data, as of now. Mapper is provided with individual files of each file where it is difficult to parse individual tags.

Answer (score 0):

Your first task would be to find a way to read in xml files and feed them to your MR job, as there is no builtin InputFormat available for xml files. See [this](http://www.undercloud.org/?p=408) and [this](https://github.com/pyongjoo/MapReduce-Example/blob/master/mysrc/XmlInputFormat.java) if you need some help(Haven't tested them personally but they look OK to me). You'll get the content within the start and end tag provided by you during the job configuration as values in your mapper. Extract the values you need and generate the output. HTH

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look into XMLInputFormat to deal with xml files in mapreduce. You can specify the start and end tag which in your case would be  and  respectively. Please have a look into this [XMLInputFormat Link](https://github.com/apache/mahout/blob/ad84344e4055b1e6adff5779339a33fa29e1265d/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/mahout/classifier/bayes/XmlInputFormat.java). Now inside each map function you will get the value( i.e the one you mentioned in your question)as your single record. Now you can use XML DOM parser (check this link [XML DOM parser example](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/)) or XML SAX Parser [XML SAX parser example](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-sax-parser/) to retrieve the required child values and you can emit those as your final output.